# Change post value in WordPress

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields

How change existing value to new and keep data ?

I changed the name in ACF and now my new data is not updated

```
$post_desc = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_desc', true);
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$value = get_post_custom_values(get_the_ID(), $post_desc);
foreach ($value as $values)
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_desc', $post_desc );
```

`post_desc` - is new name on ACF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a new value and keep the previous values, you need to use `add_post_meta()` instead of `update_post_meta()`:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$new_post_desc = 'the new value here';

// add_post_meta() add a new field with the same name
// and keeps previous values on the database
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_desc', $new_post_desc );
```

Then, you can use `get_post_custom_values()` to get all values for `post_desc` field, but note that you are using this function incorrectly.

Instead of:

```
$values = get_post_custom_values(get_the_ID(), $post_desc);
```

It should be:

```
$values = get_post_custom_values( 'post_desc', get_the_ID() );
```

where `'post_desc'` (not `$post_desc`) is the name or the field.

If you want to update one specific value previously set for that field, you can use [`update_post_meta()` passing the previous value you want to update as the fourth parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/):

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_desc', 'new_value', 'previous_value' );
```